# oAuth 2.0 password grant type example in node js

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

I am using the oauth2orize library for nodeJS and would like to find an example of the grant type password using this library. I have a mobile application which should not need "third party" authentication and would like to make this as user friendly as possible. Basically, they will have a login form in which they enter their username and password, and then they should be authenticated and receive a token from the transaction.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.